"Combi" heater style item but "portable" (ie. Not installed to the building)?
I've just had to move home. The previous place had a "combi boiler" and you could just turn on the hot tap for a bath when you need it and it was pretty cheap to have a bath.
This next flat I am in has an old style "water tank/immersion heater". Last time I had these I remember the life of luke-warm half-filled baths and it was also double or more cost per bath.
My question is, isn't there some item you can buy that I can just turn the sink tap on (attached to a hose of course for inlet), then using another hose just output hot water into the bathtub?
I realise that an electric shower basically does what I am saying. I actually bought some cheap thing of Ebay and never unboxed it. Is there any reason why these are not commonplace? Maybe they are commonplace, if so can someone recommend a good one to me?
(You probably realise I am not DIY savvy and certainly don't want to be installing any devices to the actual building, which I am just renting a room inside)
Thanks for all help or suggestions.

If you Google portable hot water system you'll find many devices that would do what you mention, fired by propane, and used primarily for camping. Propane is generally the most expensive way to heat water, so I'm not making this an answer because it doesn't solve your problem. So yes it exists, but no, it wouldn't be cheaper to operate than what you have now. And you would need good ventilation to boot.

It’s not clear if your current water heater is grossly underprovisioned. If you’re sharing it, clearly there will be peak times when it spits out less hot water (to your point about half-filled lukewarm…) but there might be times when it’s hot and full and you can soak in style.

The main problem with tanks is they have only so much hot water at a time, before it needs re-heating.  It is more a timing issue than enough hot water.  First one gets the hot stuff.

Yeah I haven't moved in yet but I'm trying to think ahead... I doubt it's a shared tank but I'll have to look into it. Propane seems expensive, I need something that instantly heats the water as it comes through the tap

absolute gimps on this website downvoting this. get a life honestly. you are a gimp whoever did that.

A portable instant heater would have to plug in. You're limited by the maximum power you can get from a single socket. Where I am that's 3kW, but electric showers start at 7.2kW (even on low mine is 4.5kW). What voltage and current can you get from a socket near your bath (no extension leads at this power)?

Also what is the power rating of your immersion heater, and does it have a bath/shower switch?  With a bit more information it would bepossible to estimate how long it has to run for to make enough hot water for a bath, probably longer than you think

Calling people gimp when you haven’t taken the tour is pretty poor form. And at the moment, there are no downvotes, but you might deserve it for asking what is essentially a shopping question.

OK sorry my mistake. I see "0" and thought this means everyone downvotes it. You are not gimps, I take it back. You tried to help. Thanks anyway, sorry I am under stress (not a good excuse I know!) Sorry again
